# Using cascade on Entities with Id().GeneratedBy.Assigned()

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, cascade

From the NHibernate docs:

> Due to its inherent nature, entities that use this generator cannot be
>   saved via the ISession's SaveOrUpdate() method. Instead you have to
>   explicitly specify to NHibernate if the object should be saved or
>   updated by calling either the Save() or Update() method of the
>   ISession.

OK, so when these entities are children of another entity, and you want to use cascade so that when the parent is saved it's children are persisted too, how can we given that we are supposed to choose `Save` or `Update`?

Am I supposed to blow my Aggregate Root away and start saving individual children? How hard would it have been to cover this in the framework? I shouldn't have to turn the lights off when I leave the crapper, it should be automatic me thinks.

Comment: Good one! looking forward any answer...

Comment: how is the Id assigned? could you possibly implement and idgenerator and have a unsavedValue set?

Comment: i have an import system, where the source file has guids pre-defined, which may or may not exist in the destination db.. so I am assigning the id in code, checking for existence in the database first, which leads me to decide to save or update...it does not seem unreasonable to me for me to expect NH to do this existence checking for me for entities where the id is assigned...i.e. SaveOrUpdate

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, with a slight and not completely objectionable side effect.

If we use `Version` and `UnsavedValue` configurations, we are able to use `SaveOrUpdate()` once more with our entities and cascades work as expected.

However, because the Version value is handled db-side, NH has to make a second call to retrieve the latest version (in my case a timestamp).

I much prefer aggregate roots handling saves of children so it works for me.

...

```
public virtual byte[] Version { get; set; }
```

...

```
mapping.Version(m => m.Version)
.UnsavedValue(null)
.CustomSqlType("timestamp")
.CustomType("BinaryBlob")
.Generated.Always();
```